# No Display while coding pong game in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, pong

My code gives a black box output of 600*800 dimensions with no other display.

I have tried to code a basic pong game the anonymous function calls the update() function periodically which calls reset() accordingly

```
<canvas id = "gc" width = "640" height = "480"> </canvas>
<script>
userPlankYPosition =40;
computerPlankYPosition = 40;
plankWidth = 10;
plankHeight =100;
ballPositionX=ballPositionY=50;
ballDimension =6;
XVelocity=YVelocity=4;
playerScore=ComputerScore=0;
computerPlankSpeedinY=4;
var canvas,canvasContext;
    window.onload=function() {
        canvas=document.getElementById('gc');
        canvasContext=canvas.getContext('2d');
        setInterval(update, 1000/30);

    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove',function(e){
        userPlankYPosition = e.clientY-plankHeight/2;
    });
};
function reset(){
    ballPositionX=canvas.width/2;
    ballPositionY=canvas.height/2;
    XVelocity-=XVelocity;
    YVelocity=3;
};
function update(){
    canvasContext.fillstyle='black';
    canvasContext.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    canvasContext.fillstyle='white';
    canvasContext.fillRect(0,userPlankYPosition,plankWidth,plankHeight);
    canvasContext.fillRect(canvas.width-plankWidth,computerPlankYPosition,plankWidth,plankHeight);
    canvasContext.fillRect(ballPositionX-ballDimension/2,ballPositionY-ballDimension/2,ballDimension,ballDimension);
    canvasContext.fillText(playerScore,100,100);
    canvasContext.fillText(ComputerScore,canvas.width-100,100); 
    ballPositionX+=XVelocity;
    ballPositionY+=YVelocity;
    if(ballPositionY<0 && YVelocity <0){
        YVelocity-=YVelocity;
    }
    if(ballPositionY>canvas.height && YVelocity <0){
        YVelocity-=YVelocity;
    }
    if(ballPositionX<0 )
    {
        if(ballPositionY>userPlankYPosition && ballPositionY<userPlankYPosition+plankHeight){
            XVelocity-=XVelocity;
            dy=ballPositionY-(userPlankYPosition+plankHeight/2);
            YVelocity = dy*0.3;
        }
        else{
            ComputerScore++;
            reset();
        }
    }

    if(ballPositionX>canvas.width )
    {
        if(ballPositionY>computerPlankYPosition && ballPositionY<computerPlankYPosition+plankHeight){
            XVelocity-=XVelocity;
            dy=ballPositionY-(computerPlankYPosition+plankHeight/2);
            YVelocity = dy*0.3;
        }
        else{
            playerScore++;
            reset();
        }
    };
    if(computerPlankYPosition+plankHeight/2<ballPositionY){
        computerPlankYPosition+=computerPlankSpeedinY;
    }
    else{
        computerPlankYPosition-=computerPlankSpeedinY;
    }
    // canvasContext.fillstyle='black';
    // canvasContext.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    // canvasContext.fillstyle='white';
    // canvasContext.fillRect(0,userPlankYPosition,plankWidth,plankHeight);
    // canvasContext.fillRect(canvas.width-plankWidth,computerPlankYPosition,plankWidth,plankHeight);
    // canvasContext.fillRect(ballPositionX-ballDimension/2,ballPositionY-ballDimension/2,ballDimension,ballDimension);
    // canvasContext.fillText(playerScore,100,100);
    // canvasContext.fillText(ComputerScore,canvas.width-100,100);      
};
```

and the output is :[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMvAY.png)

Comment: You should probably use meaningful variable names. It is painful to read...

Comment: ok should i edit the code and post ?

Comment: I think so. It is hard to help you if we cannot understand what your code is doing.

Comment: Just a note: you are only calling update once, because you pass the evaluation of update to setInterval. Instead, call it like `setInterval(update, 1000/30);`

Comment: @Badacadabra I have edited the code according to the variable names

Comment: @chazsolo I have changed the call statement to update but the problem persists

Comment: It's `context.fillStyle`, not `context.fillstyle`. Voting to close as typo.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling update from setInterval without the parenthesis.

Comment: I tried calling update without the paranthesis but the problem persists.